# Change margin when orientation change?

Tags: android, user-interface

`public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);


     TextView forgot_pswrd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

         int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

            if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

                    forgot_pswrd.setLayoutParams(llp);


            }
            else{




            }

    }`

how change margin when the orientation change ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two layout XML files with different layouts for both portrait and landscape orientation and to put one in `layout-port` folder, and the other in `layout-land` folder. When the orientation changes the layout will also change according to the orientation.